# tomcat connection pool validation interval

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat connection  pool (tomcat 7) in my application (java application) to connect to a remote Oracle DB on an Azure machine. My connection pool configuration is as follow:

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setUrl(connString);
p.setUsername(user);
p.setPassword(password);
p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
p.setValidationInterval(1 * 60000/2);
p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1 * 60000/2);
p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
p.setTestWhileIdle(true);
p.setMinIdle(10);
p.setInitialSize(10);
```

However looking at the capture file, I see that the connections are not checked every 30 seconds as I expected. One connection is checked correctly, the others are checked after 3 times the configuration (180 second). then again only some of the connections are checked and after a while it seems to stable on twice the configuration period (every 60 seconds).

I tested it with different configured time and different pool size, all had a instability period in which each time only part of the connections were checked and eventually it stabled on checks of all the connections every twice the configured time.
What am I missing?
Thanks,

Nir

Comment: The server closing the connection shouldn't even really be a problem as the pool should also check for stale connections. I would guess not any of it is happening because you're maybe putting the configuration in the wrong place. I'd detail that a little more.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation

> Validation intervals - we don't have to validate every single time we use the connection, we can do this when we borrow or return the connection, just not more frequent than an interval we can configure.

I assume validation interval is minimum time between checks and depends on how often connection is used.